# How to make a traverse that collects the absolute maximum amount of points?

Tags: python, oop, matrix

We have a traverse that starts from any element from the first row, gains its energy and he must gather the maximum amount of energy from that starting position until it reaches the last row, he moves only to (i+1, j+1) or (i+1, j-1) or (i+1, j) and he a fixed amount of energy while moving.

I've tried a greedy approach and sometimes it tells me "list index out of range" in the lines where I wrote the directions and i think there is a better way to do it but can't figure it out, thanks in advance

```
import random

class robot:
    def __init__(self, column, row = 0):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.power = a[row][column]
        self.consume = random.randint(1,5)

    def left(self):
        self.row = self.row + 1
        self.column = self.column - 1
        self.power = self.power + a[self.row][self.column] - self.consume

    def right(self):
        self.row = self.row + 1
        self.column = self.column + 1
        self.power = self.power + a[self.row][self.column] - self.consume

    def center(self):
        self.row = self.row + 1
        self.power = self.power + a[self.row][self.column] - self.consume

    def decision(self):
        row = self.row
        column = self.column
        if row < 9:
            if column < 9:
                if a[row + 1][column + 1] > a[row + 1][column] and a[row + 1][column  + 1] > a[row + 1][column - 1]:
                    self.right()
            else:
                if a[row + 1][column - 1] > a[row + 1][column]:
                    self.left()
                else: 
                    self.center
            if a[row + 1][column] > a[row + 1][column + 1] and a[row + 1][column] > a[row + 1][column - 1]:
                self.center()
            else:
                if a[row + 1][column  + 1] > a[row + 1][column - 1]:
                    self.right()
                else: 
                    self.left()
            if column > 0:
                if a[row + 1][column - 1] > a[row + 1][column] and a[row + 1][column  - 1] > a[row + 1][column + 1]:
                    self.left()
            else:
                if a[row + 1][column] > a[row + 1][column + 1]:
                    self.center()
                else:
                    self.right()

a = [[random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)]]
for i in range (0,10):
    a.append([random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)])
x = 0
y = random.randint(0,9)
p = robot(y)
while (x<9):
    x= x + 1
    p.decision()
print(p.power)
```

Comment: So it needs to find the way with the most "energy" or the way he uses the least "energy"?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used pprint to visualize your matrix board, but feel free to delete that part. Your problem came from the complicated if/else block in the `decision()` method. Somewhere in there, you end up indexing out of range when you call a[row+1][column] with a plus or minus one for the column. I fixed that part to find the three values below the robot, then go left if left is max, center if center is max, right if right is max. The three values are initialized to -1 so that if left or right does not exist on the edges, it will never be the max out of the three values.

```
import random, pprint

class robot():
    # omitted other methods
    def decision(self):
        row = self.row
        column = self.column
        if row == len(a):
            return
        # initialize local variables to store left, center, and right values at -1
        values = [-1, -1, -1]

        # set left value if it exists
        if column > 0:
            values[0] = a[row+1][column-1]
        # set center value
        values[1] = a[row+1][column]
        # set right value if it exists
        if column < 9:
            values[2] = a[row+1][column+1]

        if values[0] == max(values):
            self.left()
        elif values[1] == max(values):
            self.center()
        elif values[2] == max(values):
            self.right()

a = [[random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)]]
for i in range (0,10):
    a.append([random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)])

x = 0
y = random.randint(0,9)
p = robot(y)

pprint.pprint(a)
print('starting:', y)

while(p.row<9):
    p.decision()
print(p.power)
```

P.S. I don't think this is necessarily finding the HIGHEST energy total at the end, as sometimes following the highest value directly below the robot will not lead to the highest path. For example, in this 4x4 board, assuming the robot starts at row=0 and column=0:
R 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
9 0 0 1

Robot will end up with energy of 3 (ignoring consume energy), but it would have been better if he just went straight down to get to the 9. So I think you need a BFS to check every possible move to the bottom row and find the max of those paths. Essentially a tree-traversal problem.